# Grails: How to assign domain field = someValue fetching from database

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Suppose I have two domains:

```
class Country {

   String name
   String Desc

   static hasMany = [organizations: Organization]
}

class Organization {
   String name
   Country country

   static belongsTo = [country:Country]
}
```

**Note:** In case of create Organization, countries will be listed in a combobox.

Suppose I have 4 row in my database which I have fetched from bootstrap.

```
**Name**    **Desc**
US      USA
CA      CAN
NP      NEP
IN      IND
```

I want to assign USA as a default value while create a Organization. Is there a way to do it from domain level not gsp?

Answer (score 0):

I think the [load method](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/load.html) is your best bet, although it requires that you know the id of the instance that you want to be the default. It's not a good idea to hard-code this because it could change in the future. But you can look it up when the app starts and save the id, e.g.

```
class BootStrap {

   def grailsApplication

   def init = {
      def usa = Country.findByName('US')
      grailsApplication.config.COUNTRY_US_ID = usa.id
   }
}
```

Use whatever Config key you want of course.

Then change the `Organization` class to call `load` in its constructor:

```
import grails.util.Holders

class Organization {

   Organization() {
      if (Holders.config.COUNTRY_US_ID) {
         country = Country.load(Holders.config.COUNTRY_US_ID)
      }
   }

   String name

   static belongsTo = [country:Country]
}
```

Note that I removed the `Country country` property because it's redundant; adding that `belongsTo` creates a property with the same name as the map key ("country") and with the same type as the map value (Country). It doesn't hurt to have it, but it's not needed.

The reason `load` is appropriate here is that it doesn't hit the database until you access a persistent property other than `id`. So you're configuring it to lazily retrieve the real instance if necessary, but if you overwrite the value with a different instance, you won't have wasted a database lookup for the initial population. Turn on SQL logging to verify this.